# Flutter: Specify "android:name" for application or not?

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

Flutter's [V2 Android migration guide](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects) recommends using `<application android:name="${applicationName}"`  in the `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file.

However, new Flutter projects leave out the `android:name` field from `application` entirely.

Does that mean it's okay to remove this field from `application`? What are the pros and cons of providing it?